ISO 8061 built-in support in RSpec or Minitest
When to_json is called on an object in Rails, the datetime objects are converted to the ISO 8601 standard automatically which is an excellent tool for sending data back to a client.
[43] pry(main)> { first_name: 'Arslan', date_of_birth: user.created_at }.to_json
=> "{\"first_name\":\"Arslan\",\"date_of_birth\":\"2024-08-21T19:44:17.423Z\"}"
[44] pry(main)> user.created_at
=> Wed, 21 Aug 2024 19:44:17.423106000 UTC +00:00
[45] pry(main)> 

However in RSpec or Minitest, one has to manually convert the time, like the following:
expect(parsed_body).to eq({ pin_code_sent_at: user.pin_code_sent_at.utc.iso8601(3)}.stringify_keys)

Just like it's automatic in to_json, is there a way to accomplish a similar in RSpec or Minitest?
One hacky way I could find:
expect(parsed_body).to eq(JSON.parse({ pin_code_sent_at: user.pin_code_sent_at).to_json)

Of course, it involves converting a hash to JSON, and parsing it back, just to have the time format right & comparable.

I just updated my question. When we want to compare two hashes, it becomes problematic.

@SchwernI I had pasted the wrong example in my question. I have pasted the right one now. I'm testing a controller, and I'm comparing the parsed response of an endpoint to a hash.

@ArslanAli Thx, I'll have another look.

You're correct that it's laborious to test formatted data. It's usually better to test the content earlier in the process, before formatting, and then only do cursory testing of the actual JSON.

The problem is not Rails vs. RSpec. The problem is that to_json will happily convert a Time instance to its ISO 8601 representation but JSON.parse won't do the opposite – it just retains the ISO 8601 string.

You're facing this problem because JSON.parse won't re-create the time object:
t = Time.parse('2024-08-30T14:30+0000')

data = { key: t }
#=> {:key=>2024-08-30 14:30:00 +0000}

json = data.to_json
#=> "{\"key\":\"2024-08-30T14:30:00.000+00:00\"}"

parsed_body = JSON.parse(json)
#=> {"key=">"2024-08-30T14:30:00.000+00:00"

As you can see, the value for :key / "key" changed from an instance of Time to an instance of String. This behavior is expected, from the JSON docs:

When you “round trip” a non-String object from Ruby to JSON and back, you have a new String, instead of the object you began with

The documentation then explains so-called JSON additions which add class specific details to the JSON string for parsing. But I guess this isn't an option as it will significantly alter the generated JSON and only works for Ruby.
However, an easier way to get a comparable structure is to retrieve the time object's JSON representation via as_json from ActiveSupport's JSON support. The corresponding key can be given as a literal string:
expect(parsed_body).to eq({ "key" => t.as_json })


If the purpose of the test is to check that the pin_code_sent_at pair has been converted to JSON correctly, you can make this easier with have_attributes. You can test individual keys without having to change the test every time a key is added.
expect(parsed_body).to have_attributes(
  "pin_code_sent_at": user.pin_code_sent_at.utc.iso8601(3)
)

You can also simply round-trip your expected data through JSON and see if they match. It's called "round tripping", ensuring the data can be serialized and deserialized correctly. This is fine, you're not testing the JSON parser, you're testing it was passed the correct data. It avoids false test failures when the details of the JSON formatting change.
expect(parsed_body).to have_attributes(
  JSON.parse({ pin_code_sent_at: user.pin_code_sent_at }.to_json)
)

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you can write a custom matcher.
RSpec::Matchers.define :have_json_attributes do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expect(actual).to have_attributes(JSON.parse(expected.to_json))
  end
end

expect(parsed_body).to have_json_attributes(
  pin_code_sent_at: user.pin_code_sent_at
)

(Something like that, I can't test it at the moment.)

Converting my comments to an "answer" as I believe it adds some context. For actual solutions please check the other answers.
The JSON specification itself has no concept of Date or Time, so technical reliance on any given representation is probably an inappropriate means of testing, unless you intend to write your own serializer that implements this standard.
Variations of Representation
Rails
The conversion of a Time Object to ISO 8601 standard is implemented by Rails by default. Source and Source.
Rails to_json implementation of ISO 8601 is based solely on general convention, the recommendation of this format in RFC 7493, and the fact that this standard is well established and widely used, making it more portable than most.
Interestingly enough if the ActiveSupport::JSON::Encoding::use_standard_json_time_format setting in Rails is turned off you get "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %z"
JSON gem
The ruby JSON gem simply calls to_s (on most objects) which in the case of a Time object is not a conforming standard "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"
This creates additional confusion given that DateTime has a different to_s representation, which is RFC 3339 compliant. "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"
OJ
The oj gem takes it's own approach representing Time as {\"^t\": precision_seconds_since_the_epoch}. This makes it possible to dump the object to json and convert that json back into ruby objects but only if both sides are using this library's implementation.
etc...
Round tripping
As you can see, due to the fact that there is no actual standard, round tripping JSON is difficult and a parser needs to either implement its own flavor of representation (like oj) or it would need to be designed to handle any number of possible representations, to first determine if the String is a date and then convert it, which as you can imagine would be time consuming and error prone.
